# How to create a assembly language that uses only the register to represent an identifiers?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

To clarify, the question:

salary = reghours * 3 + overtimehours * 2 - benifit * 3

It can not use variables (`.data`)...

This is what I created so far:

```
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,2
    mul ebx
    call dumpRegs

    mov ecx,2
    mov ebx,2
    mul ebx
    call dumpRegs

    mov edx,3
    mov ebx,5
    mul ebx
    call dumpRegs
```

okay, the two above instruction computation are correct by edx register continue to be zero?

my question is, how to get the calculation for salary that will include the reg + reg - reg with total sum of a reg?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Do each of the three higher-precedence operations in an order that will make sense when you get to step 2:

```
benifit * 3        // question: why would you do this calculation first?
reghours * 3
overtimehours * 2
```

After each of these calculations, push the intermediate result onto the stack.

**Step 2:** When all three calculations are done, start calculating the final result by popping each of the three intermediate results off the stack.

Voila: no .data space used. This homework exercise might be meant to get you to understand and use the stack. By the way, you didn't check the homework tag.

You could also do this problem by saving intermediate results in registers, but that's a little more difficult: i.e., it requires that you think carefully about what intermediate results to save and when to calculate and save them.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to [3-746 Vol. 2A](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) we see that the `mul` instruction you're using is:

```
F7 /4 MUL r/m32    Unsigned multiply (EDX:EAX ← EAX ∗ r/m32).
```

In other words `eax` is multiplied by the given operand (`ebx` in this case) to give a 64-bit result that's stored in `edx:eax`, i.e. the 32 most significant bits are stored in `edx` and the 32 least in `eax`.

So:

```
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,2
    mul ebx
```

Will set `edx:eax` to `6 = 00000000:00000006`, which is why `edx` is cleared.

The standard way of preserving registers is to push them on the stack (`push edx`) and later restore them (`pop edx`). Since you don't have that many variables in your program you could also use one of the signed multiplication instructions that don't require the operands and result to be in `edx` and `eax`.

e.g.

```
IMUL r32, r/m32, imm32  doubleword register ← r/m32 ∗ immediate doubleword.
```

Which allows you to do `imul eax, eax, 3` to multiply `eax` by 3 in place.

Combine this with [@Pete Wilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851853/how-to-create-a-assembly-language-that-uses-only-the-register-to-represent-an-id/7852024#7852024) to actually calculate the value.

Comment: Okay, but I'm just a novice. I'm is class for this and the instruct did not go over this. Chapter 1 and 3...

Comment: And how are we supposed to know what chapters 1 and 3 cover or that it was for an assignment?